# PHP return to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

What I want to achieve here is either echoing to my PHP or return to my Javascript. Right now I have to do both as PHP requires a return and Javascript is requiring an echoing. I want to achieve one of these options to work with both if there is a way. I want to return to both my javascript and php or echo to both my javascript and php to shorten my code. Is this possible to achieve?

When you assign a variable with an include() within PHP you must use a return $result; within the included file in order for that variable to be assigned the outcome of whatever the result was. When I went to go add the Javascript portion to my site I am now left with the thought of having to within my php assign a variable $noJS = true; and then running the include and using if statements to find out how to output.

if (!empty($noJS)) :
return $result;
else :
echo $result;
endif;

Basically what I'm asking is there a better way of returning the result to my javascript? Or somehow having my javascript be able to get the return result instead of having to echo and getting the result as responseText? How can I get the return response instead of the output on page response?

PHP

```
if (!empty($_POST)) :
    $noJS = true;
    $_SESSION['produce'] = include('../php/produce.php');
    header("Location: produce.php?rnd=$round[round]#actions");
    exit;
endif;
```

Javascript

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var notify = document.getElementById('notify'),
                result = xhttp.responseText,
                resarr = result.split(':'),
};
    xhttp.open('POST', '../php/produce.php?rnd=' + round);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send('amount=' + amount + '&type=' + type);
```

External

```
if (!empty($noJS)) :
            return [0, 'You selected an invalid turns amount.'];
        else :
            echo '0:You selected an invalid turns amount.';
        endif;
```

on the external page I am unable to return $result; as the xhttp.responseText only receives what I echo out onto the page. Is there a way to make my javascript and php work together so I can either use one or the other?

UPDATE:
Coded a page to try and explain what I'm trying to achieve. In this code I can't return cause the javascript will never receive the echo. Doing it the other way, putting the echo first and the return second will have the echoed text put above the doctype inside the page if javascript is disabled. which was the use of the $noJS variable in prior examples. Now how can I have it do one or the other and get the values I need to the variables they need to be assigned to without running into problems or having to use a $noJS variable?

```
               Main page:
           <?php
       if (!empty($_POST)) :
        $var = include('external.php');
        /*
            Result must be returned via return and not echo.
            If external page echos instead of using return than $var will 
      have a value of 1 telling me that the include happened successfully.
            Instead of returning the pages contents
        */
                     endif;
                 ?>
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                      <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var data = document.getElementById('data').value,
                submit = document.getElementById('submit'),
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
                        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
                            var notify = 
         document.getElementById('notify'),
                                result = xhttp.responseText,
                            /*
                                Result must be returned via echo and not 
                 via return.
                                If external page returns instead of being 
        echod than 'result' will have no value as there is no content on 
            the external page.
                            */

                                resarr = result.split(':');
                            if (resarr[0] == 0) {
                                notify.style.backgroundColor = '#900';
                            } else {
                                notify.style.backgroundColor = '#090';
                            }
                            notify.innerHtml = resarr[1];
                        };
                    xhttp.open('POST', 'external.php');
                    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x- 
             www-form-urlencoded");
                    xhttp.send('data=' + data);
                });
        </script>
                         </head>
           <body>
        <?php if (!empty($var) && $var[0]) : ?>
            <div id="notify" style="background-color:#090;"><?php echo 
             $var; ?></div>
        <?php elseif (!empty($var)) : ?>
            <div id="notify" style="background-color:#900;"><?php echo 
            $var; ?></div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div id="notify"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <input id="data" name="data" type="text" placeholder="Data To 
               Send" />
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

External Page:

```
          <?php
                `enter code here` if (!empty($_POST)) :
        $data = htmlspecialchars($_POST['data'], ENT_QUOTES);
        if (strlen($data) > 5) :
            return [1, 'Your input was longer than 5 characters!'];
            /* Must return instead of echo for the variable $var to have 
                 the value otherwise $var will be equal to 1 instead of 
              the value echoed out onto the page. */

            echo '1:Your input was longer than 5 characters!'; 
            /* Must echo for javascript to receive the value however if  
                   done in this order the return will fire first and the 
             echo will never happen. If done in other order the echoed text 
   will be echoed out onto the top of the page before the <!doctype html> if 
    the user has javascript is disabled  */

        else :
            return [0, 'Your input was NOT longer than 5 characters!'];
            /* Must return instead of echo for the variable $var to have 
                the value otherwise $var will be equal to 1 instead of the 
             value echoed out onto the page. */

            echo '1:Your input was NOT longer than 5 characters!'; 
            /* Must echo for javascript to receive the value however if 
             done in this order the return will fire first and the echo 
           will never happen */
        endif;
    endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: Please share some relevant codes. Text like you described above is not clear enough to capture your intent. Also, please remember that javascript run on client and PHP run on the server.

Comment: How would your PHP code be executed if there was no Javascript anyway? We need to see some more of your code example and what you're actually trying to achieve here

Comment: Because Javascript can be disabled. Javascript is a secondary language not everybody has Javascript enabled as Javascript is basically only a way for websites to hack a users browser anyway in my eyes. When you click a button if your javascript is disabled it'll post to the page of the action attribute which then fires the PHP code on said page. which is the PHP code I have posted. which then fetches the external page. through an include

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a shorten of code on the external page. I only want to do one or the other "return" or "echo" from the external page and have both my PHP and my Javascript be able to receive the data. It seems an include within PHP when echoed returns 1 if there is no return that happened which means true the include was successful. However in the reverse order if there is no echo but only a return javascript doesn't receive any info from the return as no data was echoed onto the page. I'd like to figure out a way to use one without the other and achieve a working both.

Comment: Regarding the `return`, The browser has no idea about the return, in which PHP this return is programmed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run between two different pages using http redirect

You are trying to use the famous `Location:` http header

Http redirect is not a server's work, it is a browsers work

As soon as the browser starts the redirects it does not guarantee the execution of JavaScript in that page

If there is a JavaScript in the target page, which is `produce.php` that will execute when the browser see the `<script>` tag

`include` or `require` both will render the php to browser if it has an echo

```
 $var = include('external.php');
```

If this code has an echo it will obviously render in browser, remove all echo from `external.php` and handle it via code and make the output conditionally

If you want both, then add custom attribute to $GET or $POST like this

```
 $GET['flag'] = 32;
 $var = include('external.php');
```

Now inside `external.php` you can read that value 32

```
 if($GET['flag'] == 32)
     return [0, 'Your input was NOT longer than 5 characters!'];
 else
     echo '1:Your input was NOT longer than 5 characters!';
```

Comment: Updated with a full code snippet of what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: given a simple solution by using custom flag shared between both files

Comment: Thank you. I figured this would be the only way to support both javascript and no javascript but I was just curious if there was a better way. Thanks!